Recovering Pitch and Yaw from Game View

I am a fan of the game Sea of Thieves, and I thought it would be interesting to base some computer vision-based projects on it. There's a lot I can do in this problem space. My eventual goal might be something like path prediction for firing cannonballs, taking into account the sea state. I'm not quite sure yet.
I'm building up useful pieces for now, but as far as gunning accuracy, one problem I face frequently is not being able to reliably adjust my shots. In the game you can fire the cannon at various things (other ships for instance) and obviously you can either hit the thing or miss it. When the target is close, this isn't too bad, but when the target is far, I usually try to do some ranging shots first and dial it in from there. The problem arises that when I take a ranging shot, then observe the cannonball, I find it difficult to "adjust" based on what orientation I fired the shot.
All this background to explain that my first concrete task for this project is to simply be able to calculate and display the pitch and yaw of the cannon. I've always had kind of a hard time with trig and linalg, and I'm very "self-taught" with computer vision, so I also find it hard to really google about this problem and try to learn from there. I believe the problem I am trying to solve is "pose estimation" for the camera, is this correct? Where can I find a good guide for estimating camera pose? Is there something simple I can and should be doing?
How should I best try to infer the pitch and yaw of the camera/cannon from the view in the game?
I have tried following some tutorials on OpenCV, but it's hard to figure out which tutorial matches my problem best.

so... just to display pitch and yaw? not an aimbot? okay. if it's fun, it helps learning. the CV route is certainly the harder one, compared to Cheat Engine to read out the program's memory for the right variables. -- pose estimation is a good keyword. the question is, of what relative to the camera: the world, the barrel? present several sequential pictures of the game. I can't tell if the view moves with the barrel or not. that's important to know.

I browsed some gameplay videos. looks like the camera snaps to the barrel for the aiming, so you could estimate the horizon for pitch. I can't think of anything simpler and better than a neural network for that. you could make it infer the horizon line as two output parameters. "regression". also nicely amenable to data augmentation.

this dude explains how to use visible features on the cannon to line it up... manually: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8R3ImSy8nYo

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@ChristophRackwitz thank you for your thorough reply. Indeed, I'm not trying to make an aim-bot. I know what I'm trying to do is probably overkill, but I think it works for a hobby project. I appreciate you finding that video, that was actually pretty instructive for me just being better at the game, but my project shall continue :P.
Maybe you're right to just stick with using the horizon for now. That won't hold up forever, since in rough seas you can't really see the horizon, but maybe I can just separate those problems.
I'll update my question for better specifics of what I'm doing.

if you can guess the horizon or pitch, a neural network should be able to as well. it can learn to use all the clues from the view. even when the horizon is partially or fully occluded.

or you could just track the view with traditional computer vision. then you could manually define the horizon line, and the tracking (using dense/sparse optical flow or feature matching) keeps the defined horizon mostly stuck to the scene.
